# How to select the next available cell when working with rows that hides and unhides as required

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently putting together an interactive checklist for my team.

Depending on the cell value, rows will hide and unhide as required.

How do I get my spreadsheet to select the next visible cell down?

My current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "<>"

        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This code works fine if I were to type in the answer, however it jumps to the start if I were to select the value from a drop-down list.

Is there a way for me to set this so that the selected cell is always going to be the next unhidden cell down?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you see this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916945/get-reference-to-next-visible-cell-in-autofiltered-table

Comment: Hi @Variatus, Many thanks for showing me this post. It did the opposite of what my formula did, which was that it worked with values being selected by not values that were typed.

I ended up combining the 2 codes. 

Answer (score 0):

The following formula worked with the help of recommendation from Variatus's comment:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Auto hide/unhide if table column 1 is empty
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"

        ' If active cell value changes (happens when selecting from a drop-down list), then...
        If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then

            ' Select the next empty cell visible
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell).Activate

            ' Otherwise select the next blank cell under the last available value
            Else: Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

                ' If the next cell is hidden, then continue until cell is visible
                Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop

        End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```